# Default XML for Status Notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am looking to use a custom XML for a status bar notification.

To use as a starting point, is there anywhere to find the default notification's xml code?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try that one :-)

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/status_bar_latest_event_content.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
>      Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>      you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>      You may obtain a copy of the License at
>           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>      Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>      distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>      WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>      See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>      limitations under the License.
> -->
>
> <!-- Nobody should be using this file directly. If you do, you will get a
>      purple background. Have fun with that. -->
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/status_bar_latest_event_content"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="#FFFF00FF"
>
>     <include layout="@layout/notification_template_material_base"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         />
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

See [Creating a Custom Expanded View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) in the Android developers site.

I quote:

> Create the XML layout for the expanded
>   view. For example, create a layout
>   file called
>   custom_notification_layout.xml and
>   build it like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="3dp"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#000"
              /> </LinearLayout>
```

> This layout is used for the expanded
>   view, but the content of the ImageView
>   and TextView still needs to be defined
>   by the application. RemoteViews offers
>   some convenient methods that allow you
>   to define this content...